# How can I declare a field for prefabs to I can drag it in the editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I declare a field for prefabs (C#) to I can drag it in the Unity editor on the script like `GameObject` fields or some else?

Is it possible?

I need a something like it:

```
public class Name {
 public Type _prefab; //It should be shown in the editor
}
```

P.S. I found nothing. Please, if it's impossible write me.

Comment: Just use `GameObject` and drag the prefab to it. `public GameObject _prefab;`

Comment: Thanks you, I didn't know! Just Imma beginer. I think that it's suitable only for scene objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use GameObject and drag the prefab to it.

```
public class Name : MonoBehavior {
 public GameObject _prefab; //It should be shown in the editor
}
```

You can drag both scene objects and prefabs to the editor window.

It is highly recommended you go though [the basic tutorials on Unity's website](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials), it will teach you basic concepts like being able to drag prefab objects. For example, [here is the lesson](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial/game-controller?playlist=17147) from the "Space Shooter tutorial" that teaches how to create in game objects from the prefabs

Comment: I saw it but I didn't find information about it. I don't know how to call it correct.

Comment: @Шах see my updated answer, the 2nd link in my answer takes you to a video that teaches you how to to call it.

Comment: I know how to create I didn't know how to declare a reference to prefab.

Comment: Yeah, I saw. Thank you very much!

Comment: Watch the videos for the Space Shooter, start at the first video and watch them all up to the one I linked you to. They will teach you.

Comment: @Шах Don't forget to accept this answer since it helped you. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png